# How to prove in two ways that a 3d vector field is conservative?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vectors, vector-fields

> Let $\mathbf{r}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ be a vector. It's length is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Let $$\mathbf{F}=\frac{\mathbf r}{r}$$
>   be a vector field.
>
> Prove in two ways that $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative over the set $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge1$.

The first and the easiest way is to compute $\operatorname{curl}\mathbf F$ which is zero.

The second way I thought of is that if a field is conservative then $\oint_C\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r=0$ over curve $C$.

I'm not sure what the curve is. I suppose that it's of form:
$$
c(t)=\langle x,y, z\rangle
$$
Because our surface is a sphere then $||c(t)||=k$ where $k$ is a constant which is essentially the radius of the sphere. If $||c(t)||=k$ then $c(t)\cdot c'(t)=0$ therefore:
$$
\oint_C\mathbf F\cdot d\mathbf r=0
$$
Am I missing something? Is my proof fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see that the vector field can be rewritten as
$$\mathbf{F}=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}=-\nabla\Big(\frac{1}{r}\Big)$$
Define $\phi(r)=\frac{1}{r}$ and observe
$$\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=-\oint_C\nabla\phi\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on whether my method worked? Also regarding your method, you essentially found a potential function hence this is a conservative field?

Comment: Yes, a field is conservative if it can be defined as the gradient of a potential. This is correct.

Comment: @Yos Please note that $x^2+y^2+z^2\geq 1$ isn't a sphere. These are all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with distance greater than 1 to $(0,0,0)$. I wan't to add, that $\nabla\times \mathbf{F}=-\nabla\times (\nabla\phi)$ and this is equal to zero.

Comment: @Yos The curve lies not in the sphere, it can be parametrised as $c(t)=(c_1(t),c_2(t),c_3(t))$ and we have $1\leq \lVert c(t)\rVert=\sqrt{c_1(t)^2+c_2(t)^2+c_3(t)^2}$. This is not a constant.